# Alternative to pseudo classes?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I created a beautiful faux legend for a box that surrounds some text: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtj5P/).  However, my solution uses `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes, which won't work in IE 7 and IE 8.  Bummer.

So I decided I would set out to try to define my own spans to use in the place of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes.  Unfortunately, my solution seems to work for the `:before` replacement, but not the `:after` replacement: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4uvU/).  Also, the contents of the box have been shifted upwards for some inexplicable reason.

Is it possible to accomplish what I am doing through CSS and HTML alone?  I don't want to bring any Javascript or jQuery into the mix.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to extend the top border all the way across. Then, give the text and arrow a background color to "cover" the portion of the border you'd like to hide.

Comment: Also, `display:inline-block` won't work for IE7 (as an FYI).

Comment: @MicahHenning, that solution is impractical for the ultimate purpose of this box because the background won't be a solid color but an image; otherwise it's a good idea.

Comment: What about the `legend` element? IE 7 and 8 will render that border around the title of the fieldset, though you may not make it as pretty. But sometimes we have to sacrifice beauty to support old browsers.

Comment: You still on that box? :) I would say: Stick to your solution. **It works in IE8+** - just tested. The IE8 understands `:before` and `:after` (also stated at caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent). And I don't think, that IE7 is so important to support nowadays. And it's also not that your layout breaks. Just the border on the top-right side is missing. So no big a deal, I would say.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, lol.  It certainly seems like I've spent the last month thinking about a silly box.  It's something I put away and revisited.  I saw it works in IE8 and IE9, but I need it to work for IE7.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webdevout.net/test?01&raw:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #ff3366;
    font: 16px serif;
}
fieldset {
    border: 3px solid #ffc2d1;
}
legend {
    background: url(http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/4242/spritearrowdown.png) no-repeat 3px 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 13px;
}
html > /**/ body 
legend { /* if the way it looks in IE8 really bothers you: */
    position: relative;
    right: -13px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="foo">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Model Forecast Guidance</legend>
                Fieldset
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```